# convert pair(1L,2L) to pair(1,2)

Tags: r

my problem is i'm trying to get pairs by this code:
    for (i in 1:4)
    {
    for (j in 1:4)
    {
    print(pair(i,j))
    }
    }

my expected result to be (1,1),(1,2).... not (1L,1L),(1L,2L)

Comment: `pair(i,j) ` (whatever it is) has more then one element. So only first will bi used.

Answer (score 0):

*-- answer to question before edit --*

I'm assuming you mean `pairlist` and not `pair`.

If so you can do the following:

```
v <- list(pairlist(1,2),pairlist(3,4))

if (any(sapply(v,identical,pairlist(1,2))))
  print(1)
# [1] 1

if (any(sapply(v,identical,pairlist(2,2))))
  print(1)
# *nothing happens*
```

Comment: thank you so much , it's working , i have another question please ,now instead of using pair(1,2) i wanna use variables for example:pair(i,j) ,the problem that the R display it like (1L, 2L),do you have any idea how i can keep it with the value of the variable which is integer ???

Comment: I don't understand the issue, you want to be flexible regarding `integer` to `double` comparison ?

Comment: Also I'm confused that you keep on saying `pair` and not `pairlist`, what function are you actually using ?

Comment: i am using vector called v the mode is "list" ,inside each element i have pairs "v<-vector(mode = "list",length = 10)",now what i'm doing that i use for loop with two variables i and j ,so when i am comparing depends on the value pair(i,j) it doesn't work , if i print it out the value of pair(i,j) the result like this (1L,2L) where the value of i is 1 the value of j is 2

Comment: `L` just means it's an integer, you can write `if (any(sapply(v,identical,pairlist(1L,2L))))`

Comment: To assist you further I'd really need a reproducible example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: for (i in 1:10)
{
  for (j in 1:11)
  {
     if(any(sapply(v[[i]],identical,pair(i,j)))){Y[i,j]=1}
    
  }
}

Comment: not like this :). Poste a `dput` of a sample of your input data, and type exactly what output you would like to get, and edit your question, not the comments, the post I linked should detail all this.